# Can't load BERTopic model

Tags: python, model, save, load, google-colaboratory

since Google Colab upgraded from Python 3.7 to 3.8, I can't seem to load my saved BERTopic model which trained on Google Colab prior to the upgrade.

Also, the "use fallback runtime version" feature is not available in the Command Palette anymore [It was available only up until Mid-December].

Is there, any possible way to load the old BERTopic model in Google Colab? I can't figure out the exact source of conflict.

I ran these codes to try in Python 3.7 version. I'm having trouble importing BERTopic.

!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
!apt-get install python3-pip
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
!pip install bertopic

ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.

Answer (score 0):

you can run install build essential before you install hdbscan

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
```